# How does the distribution of "features" in the hidden layers of neural networks work?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I would love some additional help understanding the hidden layers of neural networks.

I’ve read that each of the neurons of the hidden layers will relate to various features from the given data set.

During and after training, activated neurons combine to form an appropriate output from a given input.

In the case of image recognition, these features might be a curve or an edge in a particular region of the image.

[image]

Source: [But what is a Neural Network? 
(3Blue1Brown)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aircAruvnKk&t=570s)

What I can’t wrap my head is how those features are distributed – what exactly is the mechanism (high-level) deciding which features to extract?

Is it just arbitrarily breaking down the images of the data set randomly and spreading it across all the neurons of the hidden layers?

I would therefore suspect that the number of hidden layers is also therefore determined by this process.